# dba_scheduler_job_run_details in function return empty cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

```
grant select on sys.dba_scheduler_job_run_details to user;

create or replace function view_failed_jobs(start_date in timestamp,
                                            rc       out sys_refcursor) return integer is
begin
  open rc for
    select   t.OWNER,
             t.job_name,
             t.ACTUAL_START_DATE,
             t.ADDITIONAL_INFO
      from dba_scheduler_job_run_details t
     where t.STATUS like 'FAILED'
           and t.ACTUAL_START_DATE > start_date;
  return(1);
end view_failed_jobs;
```

When I try execute this function it return empty cursor. But when I make select it return data. 
 How to resolve this problemm?

Comment: How are you calling this and looking at the ref cursor? And why not return the ref cursor, rather than having an out parameter and a fixed number returned?

Comment: Alex Poole:pl/sql developer. begin  :result := view_failed_jobs(chn_time=>to_date('01.01.2013','mm.dd.yyyy'),
                              rc => :rc);
end;

Comment: Agreeing with Alex -- you return the cursor as the function result, not as an OUT parameter.

Comment: @user2795559 - and then `print rc`, which says `no data found`? Well, that's SQL*Plus or SQL Developer syntax, but the equivalent in your client?

Comment: "return the cursor as the function result, not as an OUT parameter" not important, result the same.

Comment: cause in the dba_scheduler_job_run_details view. It declared under scheme SYS. May be except grant need other privileges?

Comment: What you're doing works for me, through SQL Developer, so something seems to be missing from the picture. You don't need other privileges. Who are you creating your function as - hopefully not SYS? Are you using the same date when you run the query directly? (The function/return thing is a comment on the design, it wasn't meant to be about the error - just a general observation (and [Oracle discourage it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#sthref682). As is not using `like` with a fixed value without a wildcard; works, but still looks wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using **user_scheduler_job_run_details** or **all_scheduler_job_run_details** instead of **dba_scheduler_job_run_details**?

It's usually a bad idea to grant access to dba_ views to user accounts.

Another solution would be to create the function as the sys/system account, and add the **AUTHID DEFINER** clause to the function, and grant the user access to the function.

http://psoug.org/definition/AUTHID.htm

```
create or replace function view_failed_jobs(
    start_date in timestamp,
    rc out sys_refcursor
) return integer AUTHID DEFINER
is
begin
  open rc for
    select   t.OWNER,
             t.job_name,
             t.ACTUAL_START_DATE,
             t.ADDITIONAL_INFO
      from dba_scheduler_job_run_details t
     where t.STATUS like 'FAILED'
           and t.ACTUAL_START_DATE > start_date;
  return(1);
end view_failed_jobs;

grant execute on view_failed_jobs TO user;
```